# Average per year for all years prior

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table with sales data starting from 1/1/2015 to current (as of today it would be 3/7/2021).  I also have a separate date table that's linked to the sales date.

My total sales orders for each year from 2015 to 2020 is as follows:

- 2015: 1847
- 2016: 1698
- 2017: 1134
- 2018: 1036
- 2019: 1127
- 2020: 1136
- 2021: 121

**How can I calculate the average of total orders per year for the first 5 years (2015 to 2020)?** The average should be 1,330 order per year.  If I use the formula below it takes into account the current year (2021) which I don't want because 2021 has not been completed yet.

```
Total Orders = DISTINCTCOUNT('Sales'[Order])

Avg. Annual Orders = AVERAGEX(
    VALUES('Date'[Year]),
        [Total Orders])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this below **Measure** code-

```
average_2015_2020 = 

var total_order = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(Sales[order]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(Sales),
        Sales[year] >= 2015 && Sales[year] <= 2020
    )
)

RETURN DIVIDE(total_order,6,0)
```

Here is the output-

[image]

**Note** from 2015 to 2020, its actually 6 years and as a result I have divided the total order with 6 instead of 5. You can adjust the logic yourself correctly if required.

Comment: Thank you so much!  This is what I was looking for since I'm able to create a baseline average from the previous years.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `Total Orders` measure is working as intended, you can average previous years like this:

```
AvgOrderPrevYears =
VAR CurrYear = MAX ( 'Date'[Year] )
VAR PrevYears = CALCULATETABLE ( VALUES ( 'Date'[Year] ), 'Date'[Year] < CurrYear )
RETURN
    AVERAGEX ( PrevYears, [Total Orders] )
```

[image: Table visual]